# Easy zooming UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollView` with many buttons and some labels. My question is: How can I easily zoom `UIScrollView` content (with two fingers)? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrea pointed out the `UIScrollView` already supports zoom feature.
Follow these steps:

1. Add a `UIView` (say viewZoom) to the scrollView by giving same width and height as that of scroll view.
2. Add all UI components (Buttons etc) to viewZoom.
3. Set `maximumZoomScale` property of scroll view to '2' (or any other value as per your requirement).
4. Set your view controller as delegate to ScrollView(`scrollView.delegate = self`).
5. Implement `- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`in view controller and return the "viewZoom" you added to the scroll view from this method.

Answer (score 2):

`UIScrollView`s already support zoom using pinch gesture, you just need to implement the delegate method

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Return the view that you want to zoom
    return self.viewZoom;
}
```

Returning the view you want to zoom.